# Como mostrar o valor de uma variável que esta em outra pagina html

Tags: html, variáveis, csv

O problema é o seguinte: preciso ver alguns valores que são atualizados a cada 3 segundos em um arquivo que pode ser um `.html`, `.csv`, `.txt` ou `.css`,  qualquer extensão que seja possível visualizar no bloco de notas.

Ficaria assim

`./diretório/Pagina1.html ou .csv ou .txt`

```
var x=10

var y=20

var z=30
```

`./diretório/Pagina2.html`

```
Temperatura X [show var x]

Temperatura Y [show var y]

Temperatura Z [show var z]
```

OBS: Quando atualizar o valor na variável na página 1 teria que atualizar o valor na tag da página 2.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você apenas deseja capturar o valor da variável em qualquer extensão que abra no bloco de notas, aconselho-lhe que faça isso com `javascript`.

No arquivo1 **.js** deve ter:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var z = 30;
```

E a sua página `.html`, deve ter acesso a esse arquivo `.js`. Você consegue isso assim:

```
 <script src="arquivo1.js" ></script>
```

Saí do pressuposto que ele está no mesmo diretório que seu html.

Depois basta fazer com que as suas tags mostrem as variáveis:

**HTML**

```
<p id="x"></p>
<p id="y"></p>
<p id="z"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
```

Caso você queira que esse valores sejam atualizados sem a necessidade de recarregar a página, com um intervalo de 3s, como você disse na pergunta, basta acrescentar isso ao seu javascript dentro da página html:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
  this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
setInterval(function() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "require.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].insertBefore(script, document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0]);
  document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].remove();
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Muito bom. Resolveu meu problema. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Samir, você poderia me ajudar em mais uma coisa... quando utilizo o <p id="z"></p> fica um espaço entre os tags. não consigo tirar. gostaria de mostrar [Valor = id °C] estão ficando em linhas separadas.

Comment: Utilize a mesma tag, coloque `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x + " °C";` . Era isso?

Comment: Blz... Isso mesmo. Obrigado.